# how to suppress change event to allow full value to be used during vlookup?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a combobox with names and ID #s. Beneath it are two option buttons: `name` and `employee ID`. the user can click either or any start typing out to populate the desired value in the combo box.

I then have a text box beneath to do a vlookup to populate that employees manager name. Everything is working, but the change event isn't letting me type in the full value I want, only the first instance. for example: if I want to type in the employee ID 12345, the change event will trigger once I type in 1 and execute the sub with the first value it finds. How do I allow this to let me fully type in what I want before the lookup is triggered?

code:

```
Private Sub cmbEmployee_Change()
    Dim strID, vMgrName
    If optID = True Then 'if user clicks on employee ID option button
        strID = Left(cmbEmployee, 7) 'find the employee ID on left in combo box
    Else
        strID = Right(cmbEmployee, 7) 'find the employee ID on right in combo box
    End If
    vMgrName = Application.VLookup(strID, _
                    Worksheets("MasterDB").Range("A:U"), 21, False) 'find mgr name in column U
    txtMgrName.Value = IIf(IsError(vMgrName), "-", vMgrName)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your "change" event to "AfterUpdate"

```
   Private Sub cmbEmployee_AfterUpdate()
       MsgBox "macro triggered"
   End Sub
```

alternatively you could prevent macro from triggering until value is not long enough

```
    Private Sub cmbEmployee_Change()
        If Len(Me.cmbEmployee.Value) > 5 Then
            MsgBox "macro triggered"
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: ok so this worked, but it doesn't just populate the manager in real time, I have to click on the txtMgrName box first for the value to populate?

Comment: When you finish typing, just press enter.

Comment: I've utilized things in the past like this and never had to press enter, it would update in real time as I'm typing or backspacing.. is there a way around pressing enter? the end-user may get confused with that

Comment: Check alternative after edit using minimal length  to trigger.